# Re-render of the custom BufferGeometry crashes in react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a react-three-fiber app, which renders custom BufferGeometry cone.
On the frontend I got some user inputs for setting parameters like height, radius etc.
Then I send this data to the server via post request and the server sends back coordinates and normals arrays.
At first request, all works fine.
But then, when a user for example changes height a little - the app crashes with:

```
[.WebGL-0000704C00336700] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call
```

When I `console.log` these new data arrays, they are as expected.
Apparently, something wrong with my React implementation.

The code follows:

```
function App() {
  const [coneData, setConeData] = useState({});
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(5);
  const [radius, setRadius] = useState(3);
  const [segments, setSegments] = useState(3);

  const sendConeParams = useCallback(async () => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      `/api`,
      { height, radius, segments },
      config
    );
    setConeData(data);
  }, [height, radius, segments]);

  useEffect(() => {
    sendConeParams();
  }, [sendConeParams]);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="canvas-container">
        <Canvas>
          <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
          <spotLight position={[10, 10, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} />
          <pointLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} />
          {coneData.conePositions && coneData.coneNormals ? (
            <Cone
              position={[0, 0, 0]}
              triangulation={coneData.conePositions}
              normals={coneData.coneNormals}
            />
          ) : (
            ""
          )}

          <OrbitControls />
        </Canvas>
      </div>
      <Controls
        height={height}
        radius={radius}
        segments={segments}
        setHeight={setHeight}
        setRadius={setRadius}
        setSegments={setSegments}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really how react-three-fiber is intended to be used. If you want to draw a cone and then have it dynamically altered by the user, do so declaratively.

Something similar to this ...

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'

function Box(props) {

    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'orange'} />
    </mesh>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Canvas>
    <ambientLight />
    <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
    <Box position={[1.2, 0, 0]} />
  </Canvas>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Instead of a box, use whatever geometry you want. Pass the parameters you want the user to be able to alert as properties of the  equivalent. When they change, the item will re render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Joshua.
Yes, it's probably the right way to do this in react-three-fiber.
While I was tinkering trying to solve this, I came to the point of passing my geometry as a function prop to the cone.
I also implemented useMemo to some probable performance increase.
You can see the resulting project here: https://github.com/agt-ru/cone3d